# How to use an Arduino Uno as an FTDI programmer?

Tags: arduino

Good evening, I've got an **Arduino Uno** board and I recently wanted to purchase an **Ethernet Shield** extension, in order to set up a small webserver. Unfortunately I ordered the wrong item and got a seperate **Arduino Ethernet** board now, which can't be programmed as easily as an Arduino Uno board and needs to be used seperately.

As you can see in the image below, I can't unplug/remove the atmega from my Uno board as shown in some tutorials on the internet and thus I wasn't able to use it as an ISP yet.

My question is can I use this Arduino Uno (R3 revision) board to program the Ethernet one without having to spend additional money on sort of an FTDI programmer (or programmer cable)?

I attempted to connect the **RX**, **TX**, **GND** and **5V** pins of the boards since those are apparently programmed via RX/TX anyway, but that attempt failed paltry.

Maybe someone can help me out.

**Current setup:**

[image]

***(Downscaled for web view, full size image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SeMJk.jpg))***

Comment: An arduino for a webserver? You are a brave person. Just get a $35 raspberry pi haha.

Comment: lol yes that would have been cheaper and quite a lot easier I guess, but I already had this Uno board so I was like why not use it. Not a real webserver actually but I have a GSM gateway and want to use this "webserver" to receive messages so that people can send text messages via my website at some later time. So not too much of load in the end.

Comment: I still havent advanced that far with my Arduino yet. I can do basic coding on it but something like that would be some research. I did however get my raspberry pi up and running as a webserver. That was VERY easy. sudo apt-get install apache2  lol

Comment: Uhm would use lighttpd on small hardware such as a raspberry. It's way... lighter. ;-) But OT: y u no wanna help me :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the FTDI of the UNO. But it is not as documented or typical as the Arduino ArduinoISP, as mentioned by @John b.

To do so, Remove the ATmega328. Then Rx(D0) and Tx(D1) to the targets Serial Connector. However, it may be simpler just to use jumper wire from Shield Header to Header, rather than between Serial Port to Header. Where your picture looks basically correct. with Rx(D0) to Tx(D1) and Tx(D1) to Rx(D0). Along with power and GND.

But then just as importantly connect the RESET's together. Your above picture does not show Reset or the Green wire being used. The IDE will toggle the Serial PORTs RTS causing the reset into the BootLoader. You could try to time the grounding of this wire, or pressing the targets reset button, when your IDE state's uploading. but it would be simpler just to jump the RESETS.

---

Adding PCB of jump point for UNO's FDTI DTR(source of RESET, before Cap C5).
PCB Layout of Uno's SMT FTDI w/RESET highlighted

[image]
[image: PCB Layout of Uno's SMT FTDI w/RESET highlighted]

[image]

Adding picture of DTR on your UNO SMD

hmmm... I see the latest cad files are slightly different, then your release. There is a 2nd Cap, next to the target area. I suspect I have the correct Cap circled. The correct Cap's other end is connected to the Reset-EN Cut/Jump.

[image]

Comment: This is a cool way to write to an Arduino. But @Beta can't remove the ATmeag328, (he has a SMD version). If the normal Arduino is still operating when the serial buss tries to program, it will not work.

Comment: Missed that. Instead jumper the UNO's RESET to GND, to disable the ATmega328. And manually press the RESET of the Arduino Ethernet at the correct time. This is the way the original ArduinoBLueTooths were done. Alternately, one could temporarily solder the Reset of the target to C5(toward FTDI), as to have the reset automatically.

Comment: I managed to program it successfully with your instructions! But only once. After trying to upload my sketch for a second time it said the "programmer is not responding". Right now I have UnoTx->EthRx, UnoRx->EthTx, UnoGnd->UnoReset, Uno5V->Eth5V, UnoGnd->EthGnd, UnoReset->EthReset. So I probably misunderstood something.

Comment: So you are close. I suspect the issue is with UnoReset->EthReset. It should be UnoDTR->EthReset. Where the FTDI's DTR is not on a Header. I have added pictures of where it can be jumped from.

Comment: Or you can leave the EthReset unconnected and manually time the button of the EthReset. There is a 5second window. The ArduinoBT is similiar in that it has no Automatic RESET to instigate bootloader. Take note of the Resets on http://arduino.cc/en/Guide/ArduinoBT, ignore Pin7 BT reset.

Comment: As @John B mentions the more documented ArduinoISP method works. However, note that when flashing sketches via ISP the boot loader get's wiped. And when isp'ing boot loader the sketch gets wiped. Which is simple enough to put back on via ISP. For when you get a FDTI programmer.

Comment: Oh damn I guess I'm too stupid to understand these pictures lol. So I connect the reset connector with the connector to the reset-connector of my atmega? (I'm careful as I don't really want to screw the ATMEGA up lol)

Comment: I do recommend the PTH (through hole). For beginners, as it can replace the AtMega. but also for advanced users, as it is more flexible. to pull and adhoc the chip.

Comment: Thank you for the very detailed answer! I changed this question to a bounty question now and will send +50 in 23 hours. :)

Comment: "Rx(D0) to Tx(D1) and Tx(D1) to Rx(D0)" Counterintuitive as it may seem, that is incorrect for this application. The reason is that the silkscreen labels are referring to the ATmega328P but you're not using that chip on the Uno, you're using the USB-serial chip, which is connected to the ATmega328 (and thus to pins 0 and 1) RX-TX, TX-RX. So by connecting the pins marked RX-RX, TX-TX actually gives you the correct RX-TX, TX-RX connection between the USB-serial chip on the Uno and the ATmega328P on the Arduino Ethernet.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use the onboard USB-serial-converter of any Arduino that has a removable chip. Remove the chip from the arduino and wire a female connector up like as in the following image. Note the sketch is for 5 V circuits; for 3.3V use the other power pin on the board. Afterwards, you can program whatever connected via FTDI like your regular Arduino. Just select the board you are interfacing to under `Tools`/`Board` in the Arduino IDE.

[image]

Source: http://www.instructables.com/id/Arduino-Examples-2-Use-an-Arduino-as-a-FTDI-Progr/

Answer (score 2):

### Disclaimer

I have never used a Arduino Ethernet Board

http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardEthernet

"It is possible to program the Arduino Ethernet board in two ways: through the 6 pin serial programming header, or with an external ISP programmer."
b/c You don't have a 6 pin serial, you should try programming Ethernet board with an ISP(in series programmer).

You can use a normal Arduino as an ISP. There is a very good guide for doing this here.( I have used this guide successfully in the past.)

http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ArduinoISP

Basically you program your normal Arduino to think it is an ISP, then you wire your normal Arduino on the the Ethernet Arduino, by bridging their SPI busses, Pins 11,12,13 ( and tying pint 10 to reset). Then you tell the sketch to upload via ISP, to the Arduino that "thinks" it is a ISP.

Let me know if that doesn't work, or is confusing.

### Also

You could just buy the usb to serial programmer.
https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9716

Comment: Whoot this sounds great! I'll definitely have a look at this tutorial tonight and post back if this was successful or not

Comment: I tried this but unfortunately I ran into a different error afterwards: avrdude: Device signature = 0x000000
avrdude: Yikes!  Invalid device signature.
         Double check connections and try again, or use -F to override
         this check. Probably a timing issue? I also had Device signature = 0x1a0080 (or something similar) a few times.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the various replies and pictures here I've just managed to use a [boarduino](/questions/tagged/boarduino)(basically solder-yourself nano with a removable atmega328) as a [ftdi](/questions/tagged/ftdi) programmer interface to a [nanode](/questions/tagged/nanode) Gateway (v7.2).

The Nanode's FTDI connector is backwards from many Arduinos, with the black towards the board center and green towards the edge.

I used color coding from the FTDI standard as published at http://www.adafruit.com/datasheets/DS_TTL-232R_CABLES_V201.pdf.

```
Nanode       ......  Boarduino
------------------------------
Black,Pin1   ......  gnd
Brown,Pin2   ......  gnd
Red,Pin3     ......  5v
Orange,Pin4  ......  RX
Yellow,Pin5  ......  TX
Green,Pin6   ......  RESET
```

Some tips that I had a hard time working out:

1. The Nanode bootloader seems very picky about reset timing. Green->Reset is a lifesaver!
2. You have to cross the RX/TX. RX on Boarduino goes to the FTDI header TX(Orange,Pin4), TX on Boarduino goes to the FTDI header RX(Yellow,Pin5)
3. You *must* remove the atmega328 from the Boarduino or the programming will not save on either device.
4. Select "Uno" as the board if you get "not in sync" errors.